# whmcs provisioning model - clientarea confirm reboot server

Tags: whmcs

Iam devloping a provisioning module and I need to add a client area command for 'reboot' the server  but I need to it to be confirmed from the client before running the reboot (becuase If I add the reboot command into ClientAreaCustomButtonArray it will work fine and reboot the server but without confirmation) command, I do the following but the module did not run the reboot command.

in module file I added:

```
function gatehubopenstackwcservers_ClientAreaCustomButtonArray()
{
    $buttonarray = array(
        "Reboot Server" => "confirmReboot",
    );
    return $buttonarray;
}

function gatehubopenstackwcservers_confirmReboot($params)
{
    $serviceId = $params['serviceid'];
    $userId = $params['userid'];

    // Display a confirmation form using WHMCS template functions
    return array(
        'templatefile' => 'templates/confirmation_reboot_server',  // Assuming a custom template file
        'vars' => array(
            'serviceId' => $serviceId,
            'userId' => $userId
        )
    );
}


function gatehubopenstackwcservers_reboot($params)
{

   
    $server_state = rebootServer($params['serviceid'], $params);
    if (isset($server_state['error'])) {
        logActivity("error rebooting server service ID: {$params['serviceid']}, {$server_state['error']}", $params['userid']);
        $result = $server_state['error'];
    } else {
        $result = "success";
        logActivity("server rebooted service ID: {$params['serviceid']}", $params['userid']);
    }
    return  $result;
}
```

in my module 'templates/confirmation_reboot_server.tpl' I added:

```
<form action="clientarea.php?action=productdetails" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{$serviceId}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="modop" value="custom" />
    <input type="hidden" name="a" value="reboot" />
    <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="{$userId}">
    <p>Are you sure you want to reboot the server with service ID {$serviceId}?</p>
    <button type="submit">Yes, Reboot Server</button>
</form>
```

When I logged in as client and goto service and try to reboot , the confirmation form show and ask me to confirm , when I confirm nothing happed and it just redirect me to the product page and show the product info , without real running of `gatehubopenstackwcservers_reboot()` function.

Any help appreciated